# Example of TypedBinding in Xamarin Forms

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms

I search a lot of page from google that I haven't found any about typedbinding example.  Actually I can found this attribute in Xaml {Binding TypedBinding=}.  Any body can tell me how it work and give me example.

Answer (score 0):

[TypedBinding](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.BindingExtension.TypedBinding/) in Xamarin Forms is for internal framework use only, and not meant to be used directly in Xamarin Forms applications. I suggest you just use Binding, and one of the following options on the Binding (if needed):

- Mode
- Converter
- ConverterParameter
- StringFormat
- Source

Comment: thank you for your reply.  So you mean's is xamarin forms cannot use typed binding right?  I face on a problem that if I changed property of global viewmodel and the property of viewmodel have a lot of pages already binded.  I need manual search it and fixed new name in Xaml.  That why I found typedbinding solulation.  Could you share me about problem when you face on?

Comment: I would recommend doing a Find and Replace in Visual Studio :) Find all {Binding MyPropertyName and replace with {Binding MyNewPropertyName

Comment: If you are using Xamarin Studio, you can look at MFractor. This may help. But its hard to refactor a XAML page, when its binding context is normally bound at runtime. Loose coupling comes with its costs.